# iPhone:youtube video link not opened

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I am opening youtube link in webview using following code.

```
[self playVideo:@"www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcpFTAqvLYQ" frame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024, 700)];


- (void)playVideo:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
    NSLog(@"%@",html);
}
```

With the help of this code I am able to open other youtube link only perticular this link is not getting opened.

Moreover I use this link in browser and it is getting opened in browser.

I can't understand what is the problem.

If you have any idea then share it.

thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcpFTAqvLYQ" frame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024, 700)];
```

Now playVideo would be:

```
 - (void)playVideo:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>", urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
    NSLog(@"%@",embedHTML);
}
```

Comment: Hi friend it works but what is the difference between my code and  your code.

Comment: html string format was not correct say it was like <html><body></body></html>youtube but no like this <html><body>youtube</body></html>